# loadStrings() work, but not saveStrings(). Processing Android

Tags: java, android, file-io, processing

Im trying to make my program save to a txt file, but it doesn't work.
I tried to add `dataPath("")`, but it didn't work.

I didn't get any errors, it just didn't save.
`loadStrings("")` worked fine, but not `saveStrings("")`

heres my code:

```
int p;
String[] t;
void setup(){
  fullScreen();
  t = loadStrings(dataPath("Taps.txt"));
  println(t[0]);
  p = int(t[0]);
}
void mousePressed(){
  p++;
  String[] e = new String[2];
  e[0] = str(p);
  saveStrings(dataPath("Taps.txt"), e);
}
void draw(){
  background(50);
  text(p, width/2, height/2);
}
```

*I have a habit of naming variables like that, sorry*

Comment: Your question has an answer [here](https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/how-to-savestrings-in-android-22-8-2013.html)

Comment: You can read from resource using hrere for example: It is step by step: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource

Comment: Im just making processing program that saves to a txt